# Getting an instance of a parameterized class in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have these 2 classes

```
abstract class A
{
//some abstract methods and variables
}

class B<E extends A>
{
}
```

Now in a method of B, I want to get a dummy instance of E. How to do that?
Is this ok -

```
E temp = (E)(new Object());
```

I have control over the class definitions and hence they're flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pass in a factory object (or an instance) into the constructor for `B`. There is no way of specifying that a generic type parameter has a specific constructor, and the static type is not available at runtime.

(You could fake a distinguished value with `E temp = (E)new A() { };`, but that is well dodgy. Some of the collection code does something similar only with arrays.)

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 solutions :

- If `E` has a no-arg constructor, you can use reflection to build one.
- You can make an abstract method `abstract E buildE();`

For the **first** solution, you will have to pass the class as a parameter of your constructor :

```
class B<E extends A>{

  public B(Class<E> clazz){
    //Create instance of E:
    E e=clazz.newInstance();
  }
}
```

For the **second** solution, it means that class B has an abstract method to build the object (it is more or less equivalent to passing a factory):

```
public class B<E extends A>{

  public abstract E buildE();

  private void foo(){
    E e = buildE();
    //Do generic stuff with E
  }

}
```

In this way, if you create a sub class of B, you need to implement this method

```
public class B1 extends B<Bar>{

  //You are required to implement this method as it is abstract.
  public Bar buildE(){
    ..
  }

  private void anyMethod(){
    //call B.foo() which will use B1.buildE() to build a Bar
    super.foo();
  }

}
```

IMHO, 2nd solution is far cleaner.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your second proposed solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection in B to get `Class<E>`, then get the desired constructor and call `newInstance`

```
(Class<E>)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```

Comment: -1 This assumes `this` is an instance of a class extending `B` and resolving its type parameter with a concrete type, e.g. `class C extends B<String>`.

Comment: @Paul Bellora The questioner asks "in a method of B, I want to get a dummy instance of E", so `this` is of course a concrete class

Comment: Please reread my comment to understand it. Try it with a `new B<A>` - it will fail on `(ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`. Make sure to understand patterns before you use them.

Comment: it will fail with `new B<String>` but not `new B<E>` where `E` extends `A` and `A` is an abstract class the questioner creates. I'm using this code in production so wanna give an alternative suggestion.